# Zapier static dropdown displays message regarding loading more options

Tags: javascript, zapier, zapier-cli

I have this code for Zapier search action:

```
      {
        key: 'field0',
        label: 'Field 0',
        required: true,
        choices: { field1: 'Field1', field2: 'Field2' },
        altersDynamicFields: true,
      },
      function (z, bundle) {
        if (bundle.inputData['field0'] === 'field1') {
          return [{ 
            key: 'field1',  
            type: 'string', 
            required: true, 
            label: 'Field1' 
          }];
        }
        if (bundle.inputData['field0'] === 'field2') {
          return [{ 
            key: 'field2', 
            type: 'string', 
            required: true,
            label: 'Field2' 
          }];
        }
        return [];
      },
    ]
```

It works as expected - renders field based on user selection, however above the dropdown options I see this message:

> **We couldn't find any more choices.**
> Sorry, there are no more choices. We've loaded all 2.

How do I get rid of this message?

Comment: I am currently having the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet.

Comment: I ended up adding a hidden trigger and returning a static array there. This removes the error you also encountered but introduces a slight loading time. But I still prefer this over the error message.

Comment: Yep, looks much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use case **switch control** instead.It looks cleaner and will not give any warning errors.

```
field = bundle.inputData.field0
 switch (field) {
          case "field1":
              return [{ 
            key: 'field1',  
            type: 'string', 
            required: true, 
            label: 'Field1' 
          }];
            case "field2":
              return [{ 
            key: 'field2',  
            type: 'string', 
            required: true, 
            label: 'Field2' 
          }];
              default:
            return [];
        }
```